# How to write path to go one level up and then down into another directory

Tags: java, path

I'm trying to open a file in a `Java` program (say `Program.java`) using relative path.

I have two directories as follows:

```
ProjectWork\Business\Scenarios\SC01.txt
ProjectWork\SourceCode\Program.java
```

Now, from `Program.java`, I want to write a relative path to access `SC01.txt`:

```
String path = // <-- not sure how to write the path
File scenario = new File (path);
```

The path has to be such that I go one level up to the `ProjectWork` directory and then navigate to `Scenarios\SC01.txt`.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

From what you are saying, you should set path to:

```
../Business/Scenarios/SC01.txt
```

../ to go up one level
then the rest is the relative path against ProjectWork

In Java file when you use a relative path without another argument, the file is matched against the System property `user.dir` which matches the working directory.

Comment: So ../ goes one directory up?

Comment: It's giving me a weird result - C:\Users\...ProjectWork\..\Business\Scenarios\SC101.xlsx

Comment: I tried file.getAbsolutePath() and it gave me the above result with the .. still in the absolute path

Comment: I am on Windows. I noticed you gave the forward slash. However, I tried "..\\Business\\Scenarios\\SC01.txt" but it still didn't work.

Comment: @CodeBlue You can use '/' on Windows. I usually only use '/' in path because it works on all platforms. If you want the "resolved" path of a file, use `getCanonicalPath()`

Comment: Yes, the getCanonicalPath() helped. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

```
String path="firstpath" +File.separator +".." +File.separator +"secondpath";
```