# How to read a file content which is out of /src in java or spring?

Tags: java, spring

My project Structure like,

```
MyTest
    |--> src
          |--> .... all java codes...
    |--> www
          |--> myfile.txt
```

i tryed to solve it by `Resource resource1 = new ClassPathResource("classpath:myfile.txt");` but it couldn`t find file. also i search it in Stackoverflow but no actual answer related to this.

how to i read contents of **myfile.txt** in my Test.java ?

any one have solution please share with me . Thanks !!

Comment: You could use absolute path instead of providing relative path.

Comment: but some requerment it not possible to use absolute path. Thanks for your queck reply.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to write path to go one level up and then down into another directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9999743/how-to-write-path-to-go-one-level-up-and-then-down-into-another-directory)

Comment: Once you package your application as a Jar/War, that `src` folder will not be available at all, so re-think what you're doing.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a Maven as your build tool, you need to include your `www` directory to the classpath in your pom.xml:

```
 <build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <directory>src/main/www</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
 </build>
```

You can read more about it [here](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Resources).

Answer (score 0):

You are using what IDE? 
If you are using IntelliJ , you should set the containing folder of your file as resources

Comment: i am using Eclipse IDE .

Comment: i think you can do like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437382/how-do-relative-file-paths-work-in-eclipse

Answer (score 0):

The file is in the class path folder then it will work. classpath: filename is not needed. Just give the file name as parameter